# Replaced images link with a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm very noob with javascript, and i have some problem with this code.
I want to replace my images link when i click a button from my code. The problem is my images link already replace before I click the button. Here is the codes.

```js
function myFunction(parentID, size) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentID),
        image = parent.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        image[i].src = image[i].src.replace(/\/s1600/, "/s" + size);
        image[i].width = size;
        image[i].height = size;
    }
}
myFunction('myDIV', 100);
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-EmuHtKr11Jc/UFwUpHjrXAI/AAAAAAAABfk/LePqC5gLhwE/s1600/paksa-klik-ilkan.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: There's no JQuery here, so you should remove that tag on this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(parentID, size) {
    var parent = document.getElementById(parentID);
    var image = parent.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
        image[i].src = image[i].src.replace(/\/s1600/, "/s" + size);
        image[i].width = size;
        image[i].height = size;
    }
}
//this will directly call the function and make it a small sized image
//that is why your click does not work
//myFunction('myDIV', 100);
```

```html
<!--add params into click actions rather than the js above-->
<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV', 100)">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-EmuHtKr11Jc/UFwUpHjrXAI/AAAAAAAABfk/LePqC5gLhwE/s1600/paksa-klik-ilkan.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the function immediately instead of waiting for the user to click - remove that line.

Also, for more maintainable code, attach listeners with Javascript instead of in HTML attributes (which is as bad as `eval`):

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  myFunction('myDIV', 100);
});
function myFunction(parentID, size) {
  var parent = document.getElementById(parentID),
    image = parent.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < image.length; i++) {
    image[i].src = image[i].src.replace(/\/s1600/, "/s" + size);
    image[i].width = size;
    image[i].height = size;
  }
}
```

```html
<button>Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV">
  <img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-EmuHtKr11Jc/UFwUpHjrXAI/AAAAAAAABfk/LePqC5gLhwE/s1600/paksa-klik-ilkan.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: For yet more maintainable code, select elements by ID or class, not by tag.